# How to replace rails 3 Model.scoped by rails 4 Model.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am converting a project from rails 3 to 4.2. I found that scoped is  deprecated. To me scoped is confusing. My current code in index controller is below

```
@customers = Customer.scoped
@customers = Customer.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
```

So how can I remove Customer.scoped from above code but still keep the same functionality??

As some other articles suggested to use `all` instead of `scoped`. So I tried something like this

```
@customers = Customer.all
@customers = @customers.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
```

I am not sure though if my converted code is okay or not.

Comment: Does it do 2 databases requests? If not, then you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
@customers = Customer.where(nil)
```

instead of

```
@customers = Customer.scoped
```

refer this
    https://github.com/lassebunk/dynamic_sitemaps/pull/35